# Is there anyway I can program Safari to automatically add any Wikipedia article I visit to my reading list?

Tags: macos, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Ideally in my browser would store for off-line use every webpage I visit, but since I presume there is no such at the moment, the question remains:

Can I program Safari to save every page I visit (or a subset thereof, eg all from wikipedia.org) to my reading list automatically?

iPhone sparked the question but using my MacBook to do the same thing would also be good.

Comment: On OSX you can write an applescript that does this: parse the file `~/Library/Safari/History.plist`, filter it through, and add the selected items to reading list with `tell application "Safari" to add reading list item "http://example.com"`.